# How to write s/he at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: orthography, pronouns, capitalization, personal-pronouns, slash

In a document I want to use the gender form of personal pronouns. But if I use "s/he" at the beginning of a sentence, are both "s" and "h" to be written in capitals? It looks a bit strange, for example

"S/He said no such thing."

What are the conventions?

PS: Please no discussion whether or not it is necessary to use this form. I am only interested in the usage here.

Comment: There is no convention, as far as I know....By the way, *did not say such thing* is not grammatical. John or Mary *said no such thing*.

Comment: "S/he" is confined to informal uses where "correctness" on such matters is rather unimportant.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=S+%2F+He%2C+S+%2F+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that capitalization is slightly more common. I don't believe there is any logical way to figure out which is more "correct".

Comment: @PeterShor: Are you sure that NGram shows what you want? I think NGrams ignores non-alpha (punctuation marks, slashes, etc.) anyway, ***and*** I see it shows exactly the same chart even if I toggle the "case-insensitive" button.

Comment: I think the message is consistent.  As a summary, more and more writers and readers are uncomfortable about the historical dominance of the masculine form of the personal pronoun.  Both the current ways out are problematic (as would be the so-far untried use of the genderless neuter 'it').  Probably 's/he' will prevail, then, one day, someone will drop the oblique '/' and that too will catch on (or no one will notice).  So why not be a leader and use "S/He"?  In context, it will be obvious what is meant, and (who knows?) S/He might catch on.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Ngram's treatment of punctuation is very inconsistent. If you leave out the slashes, you get many fewer hits, so I am fairly sure it's doing the right thing. Consider this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=S++He%2CS++he%2C+S+%2F+He%2C+S+%2F+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Tuffy Among the most progressive Americans, in my experience, the singular "they" is generally preferred; "s/he" is seen as reinforcing the gender binary and excluding non-binary trans people.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks 1,000 editors not to edit a questionable form.

Comment: In response to this question I have dug out this rule ... we (in general) write the initial letter of English sentences in capitals; the '/' invites the reader to choose the form to the left or the form to the right. In this case the reader has to be offered the choice of 'She' or 'He', as you can't write 'he' at the start of a sentence' so you must write 'S/He'.

Comment: We don’t write *SHe*, so the answer should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I searched [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `. ( s ) he` since it doesn't support searching for slashes. I only got three unique sources (4 results total), one of which was so informal it didn't even use any capitalization. The others capitalized the "S" only. I searched for `. he or she` and got 722 results. Meanwhile, `. she or he` returned only 32 results.

Therefore, if you're going to use a binary form, I suggest using:

> He or she…

Comment: Probably a *She or he* order would be a closer match to the question.

Comment: Who or what is COCA?

Comment: @PeterStrouvelle Sorry, I forgot to link it. It's the Corpus Of Contemporary American English.